# what is the main difference between mysql where vs having?

Tags: mysql, sql

Give me a simple answer because I can't understand big explain.
I want to know the main work of having vs where.

Example=select custname,salary,(salary*0.04) as EPF
from customer where EPF >1200;

select custname,salary,(salary*0.04) as EPF
from customer having EPF >1200;

select custname
from customer where salary >= 50000;

select custname
from customer having salary >= 50000;

select custname,salary
from customer where salary >= 50000;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, `having` is reserved exclusively for aggregation queries.  It is used to filter *after* aggregation.

MySQL extends the use of `having` so it can be used in non-aggregation queries.  The purpose is so column aliases defined in the `SELECT` can be used in the `having`.

Hence, both these queries are valid *in MySQL*:

```
select custname
from customer
where salary >= 50000;

select custname
from customer
having salary >= 50000;
```

The latter is not valid in other databases -- because most (all?) other databases conform more closely to the standard in the definition of `having`.

I would strongly recommend using `WHERE` in this case, because it is the SQL standard.  It is also possible that using `HAVING` in MySQL -- under some circumstances -- would not make use of indexes or partitions as efficiently as `WHERE`.

Answer (score 1):

Gordon's answer is precisely correct. 
I'd like only give an example (that could probably be found in any SQL manual) where using HAVING makes sense:

```
SELECT
      manager.id
    , COUNT(*) AS workers_count
FROM
    user AS manager
    INNER JOIN user AS worker ON (
        worker.manager_id = manager.id
    )
WHERE
    manager.type = 'manager'
HAVING
    workers_count > 3
```

The query will return managers who has more than 3 workers.
You cannot use workers_count in WHERE clause as this is not defined at WHERE processing stage.